# Create List of child objects from list of parent object

Tags: vb.net, list, collections

I would like to create list of child objects from list of parent object. Like If i have list of bookingroom which has one member room then i would like to create list of room from it.

eg. code:

```
    Dim BookingRoomList As List(Of BookingRoom) = New List(Of BookingRoom)
    Dim RoomList As List(Of Room) = New List(Of Room)

    BookingRoomList = BookingRooms.FillGrid()
    For Each BookingRoomInfo As BookingRoom In BookingRoomList
        RoomList.Add(BookingRoomInfo.RoomInfo)
    Next
```

Is there any short cut method instead of iterating over for earch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq and the `AddRange` method:

```
RoomList.AddRange(BookingRoomList.Select(Function(room) room.RoomInfo))
```

Apart from that, you can shorten the declarations considerably: `Dim x As T = New T()` is equivalent to `Dim x As New T()` and you should generally prefer the latter.

Furthermore, your instantiation of `BookingRoomList` is completely redundant (a logical error) because you overwrite the value later on.

Finally, you can initialise the room list *directly* in the constructor call, or alternatively you can omit the constructor call entirely – the Linq expression already returns a fully-fledged collection. Which leaves us with:

```
Dim BookingRoomList As List(Of BookingRoom) = BookingRooms.FillGrid()
Dim RoomList = BookingRoomList.Select(Function(room) room.RoomInfo)).ToList()
```

And that’s it.